# How to create multiple graph windows in R

Tags: r, graph, window

By default running an R code containing multiple plot instructions, such as:

```
charts.RollingPerformance(ManagerRet, width = 63, colorset = bluefocus)
chart.Histogram(managers[,1,drop=F], main = "Density", methods = c("add.density", "add.normal"))
```

once the first plot is created and a new line code is run, a second plot substitutes the first graph in the window before containing the first graph.

Therefore ow to create multiple graph windows in R?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new plot window with `dev.new()`, or alternatively `windows()`, `win.graph()`, `x11()` or `X11()`.

Comment: What about using ggraphics(cont=TRUE)? How to create multiple widgets graphic objects?

Comment: @LorenzoRigamonti I'm not sure about that, but I think you would have to set a new container using `gwindow` first.